# Android models layer design, synchronized or asynchronized

Tags: android, design-patterns, asynchronous

When I design models layer, there are two way to design my interface. Synchronized or asynchronized.

A. asynchronized design:

```
interface Callback<T> {
    void success(T t);
    void failure(Throwable err);
}

interface UserAPI {
    void getProfile(Callback<User> callback);
}
```

B. Synchronized Design

```
interface UserAPI {
    User getProfile();
}
```

They both have some benefit.  A is non-blocking, the UI layer can use it directly. B is blocking, but it is easy to test, the design is much simple, but the UI layer should make a thread to handle it.

I really care about agility development, easy to maintain, keep the whole project neat. Which design should I use?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, this is more a question of what you want your API to accomplish, how easy is it to use, performance impact, etc.  Asynchronous designs, when done correctly, can help with some performance and API usage restrictions.  But, they also tend to be harder to implement correctly and even understand by end users.  Synchronous APIs tend to be easier to understand, but come with more restrictions (as you noted with use on the UI thread.)  As far as backing implementation, async can also be harder to understand and maintain.  I don't think agile development models really influence this, as well as the project maintenance.  I would try to ensure those working on it (employees, open source contributors, etc.) are good developers who understand both approaches, write easy to understand and well structured code, and understand the goal of the API.

My recommendation: implement an API which has both async and sync versions available.  Maximum flexibility, best of both worlds.  Just be sure to document both sets of APIs so users know the semantics of using both.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on a particular task. You can't choose either way for the whole project, as it usually consists of multiple parts. As a general rule, each task should be reduced to the synchronous behavior whenever it's possible, for the sake of simplicity.

1. If an operation is done over a fixed period of time and isn't much
   longer than other operations, you can call it synchronously in the
   UI thread.
2. If the execution of an operation may take long or unlimited period
   of time, or it depends on some external conditions (e.g. network
   connection, system load) and doesn't interact with the UI layer, then I'd use the synchronous design in a background thread.
3. If the same operation as in the previous paragraph causes updates to the GUI, then obviously the async design should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

**Internal use**

I would say it depends on how you will be using this API interface. If it's going to be used internally then it's a matter of where would you like to handle background threads. It's completely up to you.

**Published API**

In case your API is going to be **published** then actually it depends on developers needs. Some like to handle threading by them self deciding if it's going to be a single thread queue, multithreaded simultaneously solution or combination of both. For them SYNC API is perfect.

On the other hand some developers may not care about threading and just want get the result as easier as possible. For them ASYNC is perfect.

**Recommendation**

So it's seem that most probably you will have to implement both. It's most appreciated by developers and reach wide audience. For example have a look at one of the most popular network API [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). They probably had the same decision to make and they implemented SYNC and ASYNC.

*RETROFIT SYNC EXAMPLE*

```
@GET("/user/{id}/photo")
Photo getUserPhoto(@Path("id") int id);
```

*RETROFIT ASYNC EXAMPLE*

```
@GET("/user/{id}/photo")
void getUserPhoto(@Path("id") int id, Callback<Photo> cb);
```